# Hiding column in Spotfire CrossTable

Tags: visualization, spotfire, data-hiding

I have one data table with various identifiers in 3 columns (Called BU, Company, and Group).  I created a cross table that sums the face by 2 layers – an identifier (‘Actual’ and ‘Plan’) and a reporting period (‘9/30/16’ and '9/30/17').  The table was easy, aside from the variance section.  I am currently using the formula to compute the variance

```
SN(Sum([Face]) - Sum([Face]) OVER (ParallelPeriod([Axis.Columns])),
Sum([Face])) AS [PlanVariance]
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the correct values in the Plan Variance section of the cross table, for the plan identifier.  However, it provides the wrong values in the actual identifier.  (The actual identifier under plan variance is equal to the actual identifier under the Sum (Face) section.  If I remove the SN function, the Plan Variance is empty for all identifiers that have no face for a group AND is empty for the actual section under Plan Variance.

Is there a way to create a cross table that would show the variance for the Plan Identifier ONLY?  Can I stop the cross table from calculating the plan variance on the actual segment?  Or is there a way to have the actual field hidden in the plan variance section of the final visualization?

Thanks for any help/advice you can provide!

Comment: sample data and expected results would help

Comment: I tried, but can't figure out how to add a table to this blog.  Everything I tried didn't come in correctly...do you have any tips on that?

Comment: Yes. Paste it as plain text or use this site https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format it

Comment: BU Company ProductGroup-DAC Sum(FACE) Sum(FACE) Sum(FACE) PlanVariance PlanVariance PlanVariance
BU Company ProductGroup-DAC Actual Actual Plan Actual Actual Plan
BU Company ProductGroup-DAC 9/30/2016 9/30/2017 9/30/2017 9/30/2016 9/30/2017 9/30/2017
AAA XXX 1 3 6 8 3 6 2
AAA XXX 2   4   4
AAA Subtotal Subtotal 3 6 12 3 6 6
BBB ZZZ 3 1 2 9 1 2 7
BBB XXX 4 3 4 8 3 4 4
BBB XXX 5 5 6 7 5 6 1
BBB YYY 5 9 8 5 9 8 -3
BBB YYY 6 11 10 3 11 10 -7
BBB Subtotal Subtotal 29 30 32 29 30 2
Grand total Grand total Grand total 32 36 44 32 36 8

Comment: Is this a usable format for you?  If so, this is what Spotfire is currently producing.  I'd like to see the exact table, except under the plan variance section I would like to only see Plan.

Comment: BU Company ProductGroup-DAC Sum(FACE) Sum(FACE) Sum(FACE) PlanVariance
BU Company ProductGroup-DAC Actual Actual Plan Plan
BU Company ProductGroup-DAC 9/30/2016 9/30/2017 9/30/2017 9/30/2017
AAA XXX 1 3 6 8 2
AAA XXX 2 0 0 4 4
AAA Subtotal Subtotal 3 6 12 6
BBB ZZZ 3 1 2 9 7
BBB XXX 4 3 4 8 4
BBB XXX 5 5 6 7 1
BBB XXX 5 9 8 5 -3
BBB XXX 6 11 10 3 -7
BBB Subtotal Subtotal 29 30 32 2
Grand total Grand total Grand total 32 36 44 8

Comment: you need to post that in the original question. how would anyone find this a usable format?

Comment: @SPS42000 at the bottom of the question you posted is an "EDIT" button. use that and post the data there in table format (put four blank spaces before each line). otherwise what you've put in the comments is unreadable.